# Create Variables and Dictionaries from .txt

Tags: python, list, file, variables, exec

I currently have this as my code.

```
def makeFolder():
    if not os.path.exists('Game Saves'): os.makedirs('Game Saves')
def saveAllPlayerInfo(dest,fileName):
    f=open(dest+fileName,'w')
    f.write("{0}:{1}\n".format('playerName',playerName))
    f.write("playerStats={\n")
        f.write("\t'{0}':'{1}'\n".format('playerMaxHp',playerStats['playerMaxHp']))
    f.write("\t'{0}':'{1}'\n".format('playerCurrentHp',playerStats['playerCurrentHp']))
    f.write("\t'{0}':'{1}'\n".format('playerAtk',playerStats['playerAtk']))
    f.write("\t'{0}':'{1}'\n".format('playerDef',playerStats['playerDef']))
    f.write("\t'{0}':'{1}'\n".format('playerDefending',playerStats['playerDefending']))
    f.write("\t'{0}':'{1}'\n".format('playerRunAbility',playerStats['playerRunAbility']))
    f.write("\t'{0}':'{1}'\n".format('luck',playerStats['luck']))
    f.write("\t'{0}':'{1}'\n".format('playerExperience',playerStats['playerExperience']))
    f.write("\t'{0}':'{1}'\n".format('level',playerStats['level']))
    f.write("\t}")
    f.close()

def saveFile():
    makeFolder()
    dest=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))+'\\Game Saves\\'
    fileName="{0}.txt".format(playerName)
    if not (os.path.isfile(dest+fileName)):
            print("New File Created")
            print("Game Has Been Saved")
            saveAllPlayerInfo(dest,fileName) 
    elif (os.path.isfile(dest+fileName)):
            saveAllPlayerInfo(dest,fileName)
            print("Game Has Been Saved")

def readFile():
    gameFiles=[f for f in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))+'\\Game Saves\\') if isfile(join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))+'\\Game Saves\\',f))]
    dest=os.path.basename(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))+'\\Game Saves\\'))
    print("What would you like to do?")
    print("1. Load a Game")
    print("2. Start a New Game")
    ans=input()
    a=0
    while a==0:
            if ans.lower() in ["1.","1","load a game","load game","load"]:
                    print("")
                    print("Select Which Game: ")
                    filesRead=0
                    for saves in gameFiles:
                            gameSave=(open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))+'\\Game Saves\\'+gameFiles[filesRead],'r'))
                            firstLine=gameSave.readline()
                            print("{0}. {1}".format(filesRead+1, firstLine[11:]))
                            filesRead+=1
                    gameToLoad=input("")
                    if int(gameToLoad)<=filesRead:
                            exec(gameSave.read())                  
                    a=1
            elif ans.lower() in ["2.","2","start a new game","start a game","start game","start"]:
                    clr()
                    newGame()
                    a=1
            else:
                    print("I didn't understand that. Can you say that again?")
```

And this is the file it is pulling from. It is called 'Alex.txt'

```
playerName:Alex
playerStats={
'playerMaxHp':'10'
'playerCurrentHp':'10'
'playerAtk':'5'
'playerDef':'5'
'playerDefending':'0'
'playerRunAbility':'10'
'luck':'10'
'playerExperience':'0'
'level':'1'
}
```

Now, I understand that it currently doesn't have anyway to translate what file you input into the code for what the program should load. But that's not what I'm worrying about. 
The problem here is that I want as elegant and simple of a solution as possible to load the file. That's why I saved it in the format I did. That's the exact format it is inside the code itself. 
But when I execute it as is, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Game.py", line 614, in <module>
readFile()
  File "E:\Game.py", line 82, in readFile
exec(gameSave.read())
  File "<string>", line 3
'playerCurrentHp':'10'
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And when I do an eval() instead, I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Game.py", line 614, in <module>
readFile()
  File "E:\Game.py", line 82, in readFile
eval(gameSave.read())
  File "<string>", line 1
playerStats={
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Both have problems. I'd like to just have a few lines of code if possible.
I've also tried having it go line by line, but neither will accept the line that eval is getting stuck on (Unexpected EOF error). 
I will not import any third party modules. I am working on many computers, and I do not want to have to install modules on all the computers I'm working on for one project.

Can someone offer an elegant solution to my problem? 
(Also, is there a way to simplify my reading function, specifially the dest= part? Seems pretty complex to me. I just searched here, did some testing, threw something together until it worked, and stuck with it. But it feels like it should be able to be far less obtuse.)

Comment: Is there any reason why you are wrtiing your own functions for this? You could use json or pickle, for example, to store the data and read it back.

Comment: Can't  you save the contents of Alex.txt as a JSON file?

Comment: Evidently you didn't read the whole thing. In it I say QUOTE:"I will not import any third party modules. I am working on many computers, and I do not want to have to install modules on all the computers I'm working on for one project."

Comment: pickle and json are standard python's modules.

Comment: Evidently you don't realise that JSON and pickle are part of the Python standard library "batteries included" that will be already installed where you have python.  You don't have to download anything extra.  Using these is better than reinventing the wheel.